# Моделирование столкновиения объектов в 3-ёх мерном пространсве

Tags: windows, разработка-игр, физика, c++

Я хочу написать симулятор столкновения 3D-объектов в трёхмерном пространстве, в полёте. (В моём случае объекты представляют собой цилиндры.)

Оказалось, что физическая модель этого явления достаточно сложна. Поэтому мне интересно: может, есть какие-нибудь библиотеки для реалистичного моделирования столкновений, описывающие физику процесса?

Интересны вообще любые советы по описанию физики этого процесса: как они будут разлетаться, как лететь, какие повреждения и т. д.

Comment: ну или что ещё лучше может есть открытый программный код для решения такой или похожей задачи?

Comment: @Iranda ♦зачем же править с такими орфографическими ошибками?

Answer (score 1):

Мне для физики Bullet Physics Library понравилась,
надеюсь и вам поможет.
http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/
Бесплатная, с открытым исходным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант

Загружать дополнительно 3D-модель в системную память при этом оставлять только координаты вершин и нормаль(нужна для "отскока"), и главное если 3D-модель высоко полигональная, то стоит уменьшить число полигонов прогрессив-меш(LOD) вот как раз по нему проверять пересечение между треугольниками различных сеток, это всё взамен реальной выводимой в рендер 3D-модели, правда этот вариант ресурсоёмкий и медленный. Только перед проверкой пересечения нужно проверить 1-ую фазу столкновения с ограниченной сферой или боксом, если пересекает значит начинаем проверять сетки.

2. Вариант

Создать "скорлупу" между различными частями 3D-модели, в виде ограниченной сферы, параллелепипеда, цилиндра. Этот вариант хоть не шибко точный но более быстрый. К примеру 3D-модель человека, голова это сфера, руки и ноги - это параллелепипед, тело - цилиндр или параллелепипед. Плюс к тому же легче потом проверять пересечение с лучом, чем с каждым треугольником 3D-модели.

p.s. можно ещё просто взять кукольную анимацию, там и физика твёрдого тела и т.д.